# layout_large android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, android-studio

I am new to android. I am following this tutorial in android studio. Actually, that tutorial is developed in eclipse.

In that tutorial, I need to have layout_large. But I don't see that in android studio. So, I create layout_large as android resource directory and try to add xml file. But, I can't add there because I don't see layout resource file. How can I add layout_large in android studio?

I am just following this tutorial. http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/08/android-development-17/

[image]

Comment: just I wonder, why you dont use eclipse ?

Comment: ya Linn why you not using Eclipse?

Comment: layout-large is used by android when a device with a large dpi screen runs the app. All you need to do is add a folder called layout-large, and add the appropriate layout xml inside it - or simply omit it, and Android will use the default layout.

Comment: I am not also sure. I thought android studio is latest, quite fast and developed by google? Shall I just use eclipse?

Comment: I can add a new folder and name it as layout_large. Problem is that I can't add layout to that new folder in android studio. How shall I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call context menu on res folder and choose New->Android resource directory.

[image]

In the dialog choose Resource type to layout and add to Directory name "-large".

[image]

Then copy layout you want to change from res/layout folder to layout-large.

[image]